# URLSession background upload task keeps resetting

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask, urlsession

I am experiencing some weird behaviour when using an `uploadTask` for a `URLSessionConfiguration.background`.

My custom delegate is implementing all of the delegate methods that belong to `URLSessionDelegate`, `URLSessionTaskDelegate`, and `URLSessionDataDelegate`. All of them has a `print` statement indicating that the method has been called.

I am trying to upload five images to a server, each of them has their own session with an id matching the image id.

The problem is that when uploading using a very slow connection "edge", the upload progress will reset before reaching 100% This happens whenever `didFinishCollectingMetrics` is called as you can see here: [Data](http://pastebin.com/qyJxYPqy)

This does not happen all the time when using a slow connection but only some of the time.

Anyone got any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: have you managed to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Edge networking is notoriously unreliable, and frequent upload failures are not atypical.  The way you solve this is by replacing whole-file-based uploads with some form of chunked uploads so that you can continue the upload where you left off, but that requires server support.

Answer (score 0):

Increase time-out of NSURLSession for request and resource:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[configuration setTimeoutIntervalForRequest:120];
[configuration setTimeoutIntervalForResource:240];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

Use `session` to upload your image

Comment: @zain-dev Thank you for the answer. It does not seem to fix the problem. I tried to set the timeouts to `300` but now I get the message "The request timed out." which I did not get before.

Comment: @frederik di u solve the problem? i have the same problem but with video uploding. Thanks